# using = inside bquote inside dplyr function calls

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, metaprogramming, non-standard-evaluation

```r
a <- "A"
bquote(tibble::tibble(a = 1:10) %>% dplyr::mutate(`=`(.(as.name(a)), a*2))) %>% eval()
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       a `A = a * 2`
   <int>       <dbl>
 1     1           2
 2     2           4
 3     3           6
 4     4           8
 5     5          10
 6     6          12
 7     7          14
 8     8          16
 9     9          18
10    10          20
```

Obviously, the column name is not right. It should be A.

But if I do this:

```r
a <- "A"
bquote(tibble::tibble(a = 1:10) %>% dplyr::mutate(.(as.name(a)) = a*2)) %>% eval()
```

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "bquote(tibble::tibble(a = 1:10) %>% dplyr::mutate(.(as.name(a)) ="
```

Comment: why...? .......

Answer (score 1):

The tidyverse tools have their own way of meta programming that doesn't involve `bquote` and `eval()`. Instead you would do

```
tibble::tibble(!!a := 1:10) %>% dplyr::mutate(!!a := .data[[a]]*2)
```

The `:=` let's you assign parameter names dynamically. For more info check out `vignette("programming", "dplyr")`